# Python tkinter - TypeError - 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, database, string, tkinter, typeerror

Hello please can you help me I'm trying to practice coding for fun and making a database but am stuck. Has anyone got any advice
Thank you:

I'm trying to enter data into an entry field so that it can be copied into a table in my database but am getting the problem - TypeError - 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

```
def players_one():
    global screen8
    global playertext
    global playerLabel
    screen8 = Tk()
    screen8.title = ("PLAYERS")
    screen8.geometry("1080x750")
    Label(screen8, text = "WHCC 1ST XI PLAYERS", bg = "cyan", width = "350", height = "3", font = ("Calibri", 28, "bold")).pack()

    MainFrame = Frame(screen8)
    MainFrame.pack()

    TopFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd = 14, width = 1350, height = 550, padx = 20, relief = RIDGE, bg = "cyan")
    TopFrame.pack(side = TOP)

    playerLabel2 = Label(TopFrame, font = ("calibri", 28, "bold"), pady = 10, bg = "cyan",
    text = "Player Name")
    playerLabel2.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 17)

    playertext = Text(TopFrame, height = 15, width = 90, bd = 10, font = ("calibri", 20 , "bold"))
    playertext.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan=6, padx = 2, pady = 5)


def playerfunction():
    playertext = []
    playertext.insert(END, player_name_verify.get())
```

When entering player name in the entry field of the manager login it should go to my player details table in my player login  but keep getting the error

```
def players():
    global screen4
    global playertext
    screen4 = Tk()
    screen4.title("PLAYERS")
    screen4.geometry("1080x750")
    Label(screen4, text = "WHCC 1ST XI PLAYERS", bg = "cyan", width = "350", height = "3", font = ("Calibri", 28, "bold")).pack()
    Label(screen4, text = "").pack()

    global player_name_entry

    global player_name_verify




    player_name_verify = StringVar() 


    Label(screen4, text = "Player Name : ", font = ("Calibri", 16)).pack()
    player_name_entry = Entry(screen4, textvariable = player_name_verify)
    player_name_entry.pack()

    Button(screen4, text = "Enter", width = "13", height = "2", command = playerfunction).pack()
```

Even though player name has been called a StringVar()

Here's the Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1482, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "//TDMS-FS-02/2013$/13IshKau/a LEVELS/cw st.py", line 133, in playerfunction
>       playertext.insert(END, player_name_verify.get()) TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @HammadRashid ***"TypeError"***: Here, `playertext = []` you define it as `local type list` but you want the `global playertext = Text(...`

Comment: @stovfl it is coming up with ‘str’ object has no attribute ‘tk’

Comment: @HammadRashid ***" ‘str’ object has no attribute ‘tk’"***: [Edit] your question and show the **Full Traceback**

Answer (score 0):

The `StringVar()`, `player_name_verify` is likely functioning properly.

This error can be quite easily simulated with:

```
from tkinter import *
l = []
l.insert(END, "Something")
```

Returning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 3, in <module>
    l.insert(END, "Something")
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This occurs because `END` holds the value `'end'` which is not a integer, so when it tries to insert into the list's index position `'end'` it errors.

As @stovfl pointed out it is occurring in the `def playerfunction():` function and appears you intended to use the global playertext text box, instead of a local list.

```
def playerfunction():
    global playertext
    global player_name_verify # you may need this as well
    playertext.insert(END, player_name_verify.get())
```

I would look into passing variables to functions, instead of relying on global variables, as a habit to get into, global variables tend to make a mess of things quickly.